# Can you "watch" webpack.config.js?

Tags: webpack, docker-compose

I think the question is best explained with an example.

1. startup `docker-compose up --build`, with `webpack --watch` on.
2. `git checkout -some new branch-` that has changes to webpack.config.js

If the changes were to a js file already configured in webpack.config.js, then the --watch flag auto updates the bundled files with the changes in the "watched" js files, but if there is a say, a new js file specified in the new webpack.config.js file then that new file is not compiled into the bundle.

Is there a way to get webpack to update the bundle using the new webpack.config.js configuration?